# Get value from form choice Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, symfony-1.4

how I can get value from form choice widget of submitted form?

Now it returns only integer index of selected option, but I need a value.

Below is my code:

```
$this->setWidget('emails',new sfWidgetFormChoice([
      'label'    => __('Emails'),
      'expanded' => true,
      'multiple' => true,
      'choices'  => ['email@gmail.com', 'email2@gmail.com'],
    ]));

$this->setValidators([
      'emails' => new sfValidatorChoice(
          ['choices' => array_keys($this->getDefault('emails')), 'multiple' => true],
          ['required' => __('Required')]),
```

Answer (score 0):

The `choice` widget can take a `choices` parameter with an associative array to define both the **value** and the displayed **text** of each option.

```
'choices'   => array('email@gmail.com' => 'email@gmail.com', 'email2@gmail.com' => 'email2@gmail.com'),
```

This will submit the email as the value, however now you have potential security issues.  Make sure you are enabling CSRF protection and properly validating the input at a minimum.